# A fast way to group column values within a certain range and assign a value to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge data frame. I would like to group the values in one column based on a certain criterion and add a new value to another column: For all values in column `number` from 1000 to 1999 assign 1 to the `group` column. From 2000 to 2999 assign 2, etc.

For better understanding an example:
I have the data frame `df_test`

```
     number
0    1200
1    1300
2    1450
3    1555
4    2300
5    2341
6    2355
7    2800
8    3003
9    4010
```

I would like to group the values as explained above, leading to the following new data frame.

```
  number  group
0    1200      1
1    1300      1
2    1450      1
3    1555      1
4    2300      2
5    2341      2
6    2355      2
7    2800      2
8    3003      3
9    4010      4
```

I tried it with the following loop:

```
for  i in range(len(df_test)):
    if df_test.number[i] >= 1000 and  df_test.number[i] < 2000:
        df_test.at[i,"group"] = 1
    elif df_test.number[i] >= 2000 and  df_test.number[i] < 3000:
        df_test.at[i,"group"] = 2
    elif df_test.number[i] >= 3000 and  df_test.number[i] < 4000:
        df_test.at[i,"group"] = 3
    elif df_test.number[i] >= 4000 and  df_test.number[i] < 5000:
        df_test.at[i,"group"] = 4
```

I does work, but since my data frame is large, it is very slow. 
Does anyone know a faster way to achieve the same? :-)

Comment: Loops are rarely the best solution when working with Pandas. I would recommend reading the Pandas docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `//` (it is floor div)

```
df['groups'] = df.number // 1000

Out[1326]:
   number  groups
0    1200       1
1    1300       1
2    1450       1
3    1555       1
4    2300       2
5    2341       2
6    2355       2
7    2800       2
8    3003       3
9    4010       4
```

Comment: It is not a general solution but it is intelligent:)

Comment: @ansev: Thanks. It is `keep it simple` and `whatever works best` philosophy :)

Answer (score 2):

We can do floor division:

```
df['group'] = df['number'] // 1000
```

Or

```
df['group'] = df['number'].floordiv(1000)
```

**Output**

```
   number  group
0    1200      1
1    1300      1
2    1450      1
3    1555      1
4    2300      2
5    2341      2
6    2355      2
7    2800      2
8    3003      3
9    4010      4
```